# Visual Studio 2022 Community Edit Sign-In error

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I just downloaded VS 2022 Community edition. When i try to sign into my Microsoft account I am getting this error.

[image]

Has anyone seen this before? I have tried different things suggested for VS 2017 or 2019 but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with my VS 2022 professional. Can connect to azure anymore, seems like the trust between VS and Azure is gone.

Comment: I believe that the slightly younger question https://stackoverflow.com/q/73724739/19308 also has a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) authentication issue. Azure AD is an identity and access management service. You can take a look at this resource:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/893331/azure-active-direcorty-authentication-issues.html

Comment: I am able to log into Azure Portal from the browser just fine but I can not connect from VS 2022.